# mysql jdbc connection failure error

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

We have deployed rest api based application on aws and some times the below error is thrown:

> Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:
>   The last packet successfully received from the server was 66,711,586
>   milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was
>   66,711,586 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured
>   value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or
>   testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing
>   the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the
>   Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this
>   problem.  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>   ~[na:1.7.0_85]    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   ~[na:1.7.0_85]    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>   ~[na:1.7.0_85]    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>   ~[na:1.7.0_85]    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1121)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3988)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2598)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2778)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2819)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setAutoCommit(ConnectionImpl.java:5346)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]     at
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.setAutoCommit(DelegatingConnection.java:371)
>   ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]   at
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.setAutoCommit(PoolingDataSource.java:328)
>   ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:72)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.Final.jar:4.2.7.Final]     ... 90 common frames
>   omitted

This error is thrown randomly and not for any particular api.

This is what is configured in database.xml

```
<beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
                </beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="maxwait">10000</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="maxidle">25</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="minidle">5</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
</beans:property>
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Gayithri

Answer (score 0):

This is because that you fail to connect to the database server. The `wait_timeout` variable represents the amount of time that MySQL will wait before killing an idle connection. Check your network environment.

The error log has already told you why and how to solve the problem. Go try it.